# Why is Entity Framework not using ReadUncommitted for my second query?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework 6 and are querying the database using async.

We also have an integration test running the code and for that we set;

- The test runs in a transaction, ie we begin our run with begin and ends it with rollback
- The data is set up upfront the queries
- All are run against the same dbContext
- IsolationLevel is set to ReadUncommitted

Code:

```
var table1Id = await _dbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.IdentificationNumber == identificationNumber)
        .Select(y => y.Id)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var table2Id = await _dbContext.Table2.Where(y => y.Table1Id == table1Id)   
        .Select(y => y.Id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//Code continues...
```

Reading the database in SSMS using T-SQL and `NOLOCK` hint shows data in the tables.

Running my code executes both queries; the first one is run correctly and returns table1Id as expected BUT the second one is not returning any value. It appears that it does not work to call twice in a row? If I switch the order it will be table1Id that will not be initiated with any value.

If I'm not using async/await then it works too.

Does anyone have a good explanation to this behaviour? Am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
public async Task<List<Table4>> GetTable4ListAsync(string key)
{
    var table1Id = await _dbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Ready)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //more code...

    var table2Id = await _dbContext.Table2.Where(x => x.Key == key).Select(y => y.Id)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    var table3Id = await _dbContext.Table3
        .Where(y => y.Table2Id == table2Id &&
                    y.Table1Id == table1Id)
        .Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //more code...

    var result = await _dbContext.Table4
        .Where(x => x.Table3.Id == table3Id).ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result;
}
```

Above code is close to our actual code.

When code is run in an integration test, inside a transaction;

1. Starting a transaction
2. Setup test data
3. Run the test
4. Rollback the transaction

In step 3 only the first query to run returns a result no matter the order.

- Using ReadUncommitted isolationlevel
- Using TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption enabled

Comment: It's different statements on different tables. Just because one returned a value does not mean the other one has to, regardless of transactions or isolation level. Please post a [mcve] so we can see what the context of your question is.

Comment: what happens if you remove .ConfigureAwait(false); ?

Comment: Do you use TransactionScope to run the tests in one transaction? If so, you should probably use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption`.